# Why does the Windows command prompt copy all the files that start with the specified file name?

Tags: windows, command-line

In `cmd.exe` if you type:

```
copy c:\a.txt
```

it will copy a.txt* (including a.txt1, a.txtb, etc).

How can I just copy a.txt?

Comment: Is it a modern version of Windows you're using, or actually MS-DOS? Because the `cmd.exe` command interpreter is **not** the same as DOS, it merely tries to be compatible. When I try the above command on Windows 7, it copies only `a.txt`, not `a.txt1`.

Comment: I'm using windows 7

Comment: Is this the actual command you're using or just an example?

Comment: No version of DOS or CMD that I am aware of would treat that command as having a wildcard without explicitly putting a wildcard in the command.

Comment: This is the actual command: copy E:\UmbracoControls\Input.ascx E:\Umbraco\usercontrols\ /Y

Comment: @nima: What's the name of the file that gets unintentionally copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got that idea... DOS (all versions of) does not copy all files that start the same way without using a wild-card character.  For example:

```
copy c:\a.txt x:\somewhere\else
```

will ONLY copy a.txt to that new location.  The alternative:

```
copy c:\a.txt* x:\somewhere\else
```

will copy all files starting with `a.txt` to the new location.  This would include `a.txt1`, `a.txt2`, and `a.txtyourpantsareonfire.spitting.monkeys.bat.com.fish`

Comment: This is not my idea, it's happening in front of my eyes :)

Comment: This is not the default behavior of any version of DOS.  Perhaps something has become corrupted on your system, and/or perhaps you have some sort of bug on your machine.

Comment: The problem was in the path I used a / instead of \ before my file name. Thanks for your time.